# Scrolling isn't working when there is an OnClickListener listening

Tags: android, listview

Using the [FreeFlow](https://github.com/Comcast/FreeFlow), I've setup a little app that shows images. You can view all images, or search for images.

When you search for images, you can click on an image in the results list and it will open that image in fullscreen mode.

But,
I when I've attached an OnClickListener to the images in the search results layout, the layout will not scroll when my scrolling gesture starts at an image. It only scrolls outside of the image (these are very tiny spaces)

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`View.OnClickListener` consumes the `MotionEvent`. If you want to react to a user touch (click) use `View.OnTouchListener` and `return false;` for the event, this will allow the custom view's listeners to catch the event.

Comment: Thanks man that worked! I was just thinking of implementing this because of the Double tap that I needed to capture